# Finding all solutions to a Linear Diophantine equation in three variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I have this linear Diophantine equation that I want to find all the solutions for.

### $6x+10y+15z=1$

Here is my attempt at a solution:

---

**Check if solutions exist:**
$gcd(6,10,15)|1$ holds and therefore the equation does have solutions.

**(1)**  $6x+10y+15z=1$

**(2)**  $2(3x+5y)+15z=1$

**(3)** **Let** $w=3x+5y$ and substitute into **(2)**

**(4)**  $2w+15z=1$ has a particular solution $(w,z)=(-7,1)$

**(5)**  All the solutions become $w=-7+15k$ and $z=1-2k$

**(6)**  Using **(3)** and **(5)** we get $3x+5y=w=-7+15k$

...

---

Now this is where I get stuck, I do not know how to continue. To my understanding I need to solve for **x** and **y** but I do not know how I will achieve this feat. It feels like I am missing something trivial.

---

**EDIT**

I may have solved it:

$3x+5y=w=-7+15k$

Using Euclid's algorithm to find $gcd(3,5)$ and then working backwards I end up with:

$2*3 + (-1)5 = 1$

**but we had $3x+5y=w$ so I have to modify**

$2*3w + (-1)5*w = 1w$

**add the term $l(lcm(3,5)-lcm(3,5))$**

$2*3w + (-1)5*w + l(3*5-3*5) = w$

$3(2w-5l) + 5(-1w+3l)=w$

**Giving us**

$x=2w-5l = 2(-7+15k)-5l = -14 + 30k - 5l$

**and**

$y=-w+3k = (-1)(-7+15k)+3l = 7 - 15k + 3l$

**The final answer then becomes:**

$x= -14 + 30k - 5l$

$y= 7 - 15k + 3l$

$z= 1 - 2k$

---

Is this correct?

---

Using Haskell:

`let fun k l = 6*(-14 + 30*k - 5*l) + 10*(7 - 15*k + 3*l) + 15*(1 - 2*k)`
and then calling the function with different k,l all seem to give the answer 1 which is to be expected since our original LDE is $6x+10y+15z=1$.

Using QuickCheck library to test it yields:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> quickCheck (withMaxSuccess 100000 prop_testLDE)
+++ OK, passed 100000 tests.
```

Comment: Look at remainder of division by $2$, it implies $z$ is odd. Similarly division by $3$, $y$ gives remainder $1$, and by $5$ we see $x$ gives remainder $1$. So write $z=2k+1$, $y=3l+1$,$x=5m+1$, put back, simplify, see what you get.

Comment: As for your solution, it is correct, to verify it, just substitute it back to the original equation and it will simplify to $1=1$.

Comment: @Sil Thank you very much! I just saw your comment and what you just said makes sense and seems to be a valid strategy too.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+6x%2B10y%2B15z%3D1+over+integers

Answer (score 1):

Hint:t consider the family

$x=5k+1,y=-6k-2,z=2k+1$